# Button border-radius transition in JavaFX/TornadoFX

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I am trying to make my buttons animate on hover such as those of Discord.

I can change the background color and border radius, but not able to animate it smoothly.
I could only find examples of animating shapes, and not css properties.

Here is my css code for the button.

```
class NavigatorButtonViewCss: Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val face by cssclass()

        val buttonBackgroundColor = c("#36393F")
        val buttonHoverBackgroundColor = c("#7289DA")
        val textColor = c("#C8C9CB")
    }

    init {
        indicator {
            prefWidth = 10.px
        }
        face {
            prefWidth = 50.px
            prefHeight = 50.px

            backgroundColor += buttonBackgroundColor
            backgroundRadius = multi(box(50.percent))

            label {
                textFill = textColor
            }

            and(hover) {
                // I want this to be animated
                backgroundColor += buttonHoverBackgroundColor
                backgroundRadius = multi(box(35.percent))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My button now**

[image: My button]

**What I want**

[image: Discord button]

Are there any ways to achieve this transition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX does not allow you to create any kind of animation via CSS and as far as I can tell there's no way of applying a animation even with TornadoFX. (Note tough that I just started with TornadoFX today, so I may be wrong.)

The only way of getting an animation in via stylesheet would be to use set the `skin` to a custom skin implementing the corner animation. While you could make the skin provide CSS property controling the roundedness of the corners.

Usually you'd extend `Button` adding a property, but in this case I simply store it in the `properties` map.

**Skin to assign to the button**

```
package org.example

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty

import java.util.function.Function
import javafx.css.SimpleStyleableBooleanProperty
import javafx.css.CssMetaData
import javafx.css.StyleablePropertyFactory
import javafx.css.Styleable
import javafx.css.StyleableProperty
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcTo
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath
import javafx.scene.shape.HLineTo
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo
import javafx.scene.shape.Path
import javafx.scene.shape.VLineTo

import tornadofx.*

class AnimatedButtonSkin(button: Button) : ButtonSkin(button) {

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CSS_ROUNDED_KEY = "org.example.AnimatedButtonSkin.rounded"
        @JvmField
        val CSS_ROUNDED_METADATA: CssMetaData<Button, Boolean>
        @JvmField
        val FACTORY = StyleablePropertyFactory<Button>(javafx.scene.control.SkinBase.getClassCssMetaData())

        init {
            CSS_ROUNDED_METADATA = FACTORY.createBooleanCssMetaData(
                "-fx-rounded",
                object : Function<Button, StyleableProperty<kotlin.Boolean>> {

                    override fun apply(b: Button): StyleableProperty<Boolean> {
                        // property stored in properties to avoid extending button
                        val v = b.getProperties().get(CSS_ROUNDED_KEY)
                        return v as StyleableProperty<Boolean>
                    }
                },
                true
            )
        }
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        // get rid of the property and the shape
        val b = getSkinnable()
        b.getProperties().remove(CSS_ROUNDED_KEY)
        b.setShape(null)

        super.dispose()
    }

    private fun createArc(
        cornerSizeH: DoubleBinding,
        cornerSizeV: DoubleBinding,
        invertX: Boolean,
        invertY: Boolean
    ): ArcTo {
        return ArcTo().apply {
            setAbsolute(false)
            setSweepFlag(true)
            radiusXProperty().bind(cornerSizeH)
            radiusYProperty().bind(cornerSizeV)
            xProperty().bind(if (invertX) cornerSizeH.negate() else cornerSizeH)
            yProperty().bind(if (invertY) cornerSizeV.negate() else cornerSizeV)
        }
    }

    override fun getCssMetaData(): List<CssMetaData<out Styleable, *>>? {
        return FACTORY.getCssMetaData()
    }

    init {
        val prop = SimpleStyleableBooleanProperty(CSS_ROUNDED_METADATA, true)
        button.getProperties().put(CSS_ROUNDED_KEY, prop)

        // relative part of width/height that is rounded
        // size for single corner:
        //    0    -> rectangular button
        //    0.5  -> circular button
        val cornerSize = SimpleDoubleProperty(.5)

        val w = button.widthProperty()
        val h = button.heightProperty()

        // bindings for horizontal measures
        val cornerHSize = w.multiply(cornerSize)
        val doubleHCornerSize = cornerHSize.multiply(2.0);

        // measures for vertical measures
        val cornerVSize = h.multiply(cornerSize)
        val doubleVCornerSize = cornerVSize.multiply(2.0);

        // lower part of the top-left corner
        val start = MoveTo().apply {
            yProperty().bind(cornerSize);
        }

        // straight path of top
        val top = HLineTo().apply {
            setAbsolute(false)
            xProperty().bind(w.subtract(doubleHCornerSize))
        }

        // straight part of the right
        var right = VLineTo().apply {
            setAbsolute(false)
            yProperty().bind(h.subtract(doubleVCornerSize))
        }

        // straight part of the bottom
        val bottom = HLineTo().apply {
            setAbsolute(false)
            xProperty().bind(top.xProperty().negate())
        }

        // assemble the parts
        val shape = Path(
            start,
            createArc(cornerHSize, cornerVSize, false, true), top,
            createArc(cornerHSize, cornerVSize, false, false), right,
            createArc(cornerHSize, cornerVSize, true, false), bottom,
            createArc(cornerHSize, cornerVSize, true, true), ClosePath()
        )
        button.shape = shape

        // animate open/close on change of stylable property
        prop.addListener({ _, _, new -> cornerSize.animate(endValue = if (new) .5 else .2, duration = .2.seconds) })
    }

}
```

**Style**

```
class NavigatorButtonViewCss: Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val face by cssclass()

        val rounded by cssproperty<Boolean>("-fx-rounded")

        val buttonBackgroundColor = c("#36393F")
        val buttonHoverBackgroundColor = c("#7289DA")
        val textColor = c("#C8C9CB")
    }

    init {
        indicator {
            prefWidth = 10.px
        }
        face {
            prefWidth = 50.px
            prefHeight = 50.px

            backgroundColor += buttonBackgroundColor

            textFill = textColor

            skin = AnimatedButtonSkin::class

            and(hover) {
                rounded.value = false // update corners
                backgroundColor += buttonHoverBackgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```